# Docker, TravisCI, PHP file uploads and intermittent permissions error on /tmp

Tags: php, symfony, docker, travis-ci

I have an intermittent file upload error, only occurring in Travis:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/tmp/customerDownload_1502892540/image.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied (500 Internal Server Error)
```

This is a Symfony 2.8 project running on a PHP 7.1 Docker container. There's a Behat scenario to test file uploading by administrators and downloading by users. My method for creating the file is as follows:

```
/**
 * @param string $fileContents
 * @param Media $file
 * @return File
 */
private function createLocalTemporaryFile(string $fileContents, Media $file): File
{
    $tmpDir = '/tmp/customerDownload_' . time();
    if (!file_exists($tmpDir)) {
        mkdir($tmpDir);
    }
    $tmpFilePath = $tmpDir . '/' . $file->getName();
    file_put_contents($tmpFilePath, base64_decode($fileContents));
    $tmpFile = new File(realpath($tmpFilePath));

    return $tmpFile;
}
```

It fails about 20% of the time which is a significant amount. But never locally or in production. I've tried setting permissions on `/tmp` to include the `www-data` user:group but it has no effect. I'm confused as to why it wouldn't be able to put contents to a file in a directory it had created in the first place.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening, or how to ensure it doesn't?

Comment: is the tmp folder inside the container? If so, is it mapped to something on the hosting machine?

Comment: @omu_negru it's inside the container and not mapped to the host in any volumes or anything

Comment: Check the `df -h` inside the container? Or else do one thing while running the docker container mount a host folder to `/tmp` inside the container and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani the trouble with running `df -h` is that I'd have to debug the build, run it manually, bash into the container and check but it's only a problem intermittently so debugging starts a new build. I'm not sure about mounting a tmp folder from the host. Will give it a go...

Comment: What my hunch is that container inside have their on file layout and limitations. And it may be possible all tests running on that same container are causing an issue?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the container is from a private repo so is not inconsistent. This is the only test uploading a file. I feel like creating a mounted volume for the tmp directory is not elegant in this case - seems like additional complexity which may cause issues down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be some sort of race condition and file naming issue. I'm using the same file for tests and perhaps the tests are running fast enough that it's trying to write over a file and and cannot. Updated the method to the following and so far in 12 tests, hasn't failed.

```
/**
 * @param string $fileContents
 * @param Media $file
 * @return File
 */
private function createLocalTemporaryFile(string $fileContents, Media $file): File
{
    $tmpDir = '/tmp/' . uniqid('customerDownload_', true);
    mkdir($tmpDir);
    $tmpFilePath = $tmpDir . '/' . $file->getName();
    file_put_contents($tmpFilePath, base64_decode($fileContents));
    $tmpFile = new File(realpath($tmpFilePath));

    return $tmpFile;
}
```